# El color de fondo no aparece en toda la pantalla

Tags: html, css

Hola tengo varios componentes creados en angular-cli y como sabrán a la hora de crear uno se crea un archivo que es css. El problema es que al querer manipular el CSS o la hora de ponerle un fondo a la pantalla de HTML no aparece en toda la pantalla.

Este es el código del html

```html
<div class="bg">
<div class="alert alert-primary text-center">
  <h5><b>REGISTRO</b></h5>

</div>

<div class="container alert-secondary my-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-10">
      <div class="form-body">
       
        <div class="tab-content">
          <div class="tab-pane fadeIn active">
            <div class="innter-form">
              <form class="sa-innate-form">

                <div class="form-group ">
                  <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <label><b>Nombre:</b></label>
                    <input formControlName="nombre" name="nombre" class="form-control" type="text" required placeholder="Escriba su nombre">
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group ">
                  <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <label><b>Correo Electronico:</b></label>
                    <input formControlName="email" name="email" class="form-control" type="email" required placeholder="Escriba su correo electrónico">
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group ">
                  <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <label><b>Contraseña</b></label>
                    <input formControlName="password" name="password" class="form-control" type="password" required
                      placeholder="Escriba su contraseña">
                  </div>
                </div>


                <div class="col-xs-12">
                  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Registrarme</button>
                </div>

              </form>

            </div>

            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Este es el código CSS:

```css
.bg{
    background-color: beige;
}
```

Y como verán no aparece en toda la pantalla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo que quieres es colorear la parte azul también?

Comment: No, de la parte azúl para abajo, quiero colorear.

Comment: O sea la parte del formulario también?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si le das estilo con bootstrap, acuérdate de que las clases son individuales. Eje: si le das un color al row, no se transmitirá a los demás col, entonces, tienes que jugar con el css para darle un estilo generalizado, o más bien incluir todo dentro de un col y darle estilo a ese col en especial. Lo que te habrá pasado es un tema de prioridades, una caja está por encima de la otra. Podrías darle opacidad a la caja que no cambió su color y así transparentar el color que se ubica por detrás. O tan solo darle estilo del mismo color que la caja de atrás y queda camuflado.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que de esta forma puede servirte, ya que solo estas seleccionando el área del `div` que contiene la clase `.bg`.

```
.bg, form{
    background-color: beige;
}
```